# Is == on UTF8 strings safe?

Tags: php, mysql, string, comparison

I need to grab some elements within loop base on string comparison and the issue I think about is UTF8.

Is it safe to compare strings that can contain UTF8 characters via `==` ? or it's better to make some extra SQL queries to do it by database engine?

I've done a test in PHP and looks good, but I would like to confirm it.

```
// if $_GET['city'] is "Łódź" the result is ==.
$city = 'Łódź';
if (isset($_GET['city']) && strtolower($_GET['city']) == strtolower($city)) {
    echo '==';
}
```

Comment: A better question would be "Is `strtolower()` safe to use on UTF8 strings"  (it's not...)

Comment: @SamDufel exactly it's better question. I try to use `mb_strtolower()`, but I don't know it is better than extra search SQL query.

Comment: @deem: we don't know either - you haven't explained the whole task

Comment: @zerkms I make some points list (I select them using a SQL query) and a user can input a point location by name. In this case, n points with the same location should be placed at the top of the list.

Comment: @deem: it would be easier to compare in DB then. Just sort by `:user_input = city_column DESC`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is *almost* no difference between `==` and `===` when you compare 2 strings.

If you don't compare numbers stored as strings, you're fine.

Example of different results:

```
var_dump('01' === '1'); // false
var_dump('01' == '1'); // true
```

Comment: Hmmm... the issue is about utf8 characters, not about == and === differences. Sorry for misunderstanding question.

Comment: @deem: doesn't "There is almost no difference" answer suit you? `===` compares 2 string byte by byte

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be safe. The operator `==` casts between two different types if they are different, while the `===` operator performs a 'typesafe comparison'. Since you are comparing two strings, there will be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [PHP Documentation about comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) the `==` check if two variables hold the same value AFTER that both of them have been casted to the same type. You can thus assume it's safe to do such a comparison in PHP. Anyway what you're doing it's probably leading to other errors since you are using strtolower (not multibyte safe) instead of mb_strtolower (multibyte safe). Obviously before using any mb_* function you should remember to set the right character set through `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`